# If I change Windows admin user password, then I can't login to Outlook, why?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

I am seeing this strange behaviour with Windows 7 and Outlook 2010.

If I change the password of User1 (Admin user), login, and start Outlook, it asks for a password. It keeps saying "password incorrect". I can login by using same password on the OWA webclient.

If I change User1's password back to what it was before, Outlook starts without any prompting and I'm able to send and receive emails.

Is there any link between the user account, its password and the PST file's password?

Comment: Is there an option to change the password in the webclient?

Comment: How are you changing the password?  Some methods can cause problems.

Comment: @boot13 : By right click on User in Users and Groups and rest PW of windows user.

Comment: @Ja5087: Yes, I can change webclient PW but that is Email pw. Both (Windows user and Outlook/Email) PWs are different.

Comment: Tom,

it sounds like outlook is configured to pass the local logged on user credentials as "domain\username" and since you've modified only your local windows password, it mismatches against the email server.  if this is the cause, Outlook will prompt you for your password because the password actually failed silently in the background... you really need to provide more details..

Comment: Tom, "If I change the password of User1 (Admin user), login, and start Outlook, it asks for the pasword" If you log into Windows with your new password, and then open Outlook and type your old password when it prompts you, does this give you access to your email? (If you provide more details, i will update my answer..) Cheers :)